# How do I accept input string in bash without losing the quotes?

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting

Example, 
I have this function in my .profile:

```
alias () {
    command alias "$@"
}
```

However, this executes:

`$ alias test=ls`

if I run 
`$ alias test="ls"`

How can I make it accept the string with quotes?

Comment: Double quotes are special. Use `' '` single quotes.

Comment: Got the same error for the same reason. `'` doesn't show up in the "$@" https://imgur.com/fGfHzCU

Comment: I think cat meant for you to try `alias 'test="ls"'`

Comment: You don't need the double quotes at all.

Answer (score 1):

The double-quotes on the command line get eaten up by the parser. When you invoke your function, you must either single-quote the entire alias-expression, or escape each double-quote with a backslash (or use a mix of escaped and quoted tokens). Thus:

```
alias foo='echo "hi there"'
alias bar="echo "\"hi\ there\"
```

If you're trying to re-define alias so that you can include spaces within the right-hand-side of your alias, you should instead use

```
command alias "$*"
```

The difference is that this version expands all the positional parameters, each separated by a space (1st char of IFS), as a single argument to `alias`. This allows you to do something like

```
alias foo=echo over here
```

Comment: Using `$*` won't make a difference to `alias test="ls"` vs `alias test=ls` though, so I think suggesting this is misleading.

Comment: His example is kind of, er, non-sensical.